# react-lite and vue-list templates not found by ServiceStack 5.5 web command

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to follow the steps in the ServiceStack 5.5 release notes (https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5) to use the react-lite or vue-lite templates (https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/react-lite or https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-lite) and I get:

```
'react-lite' was not found in sources: NetCoreTemplates .NET Core C# Templates, NetFrameworkTemplates .NET Framework C# Templates, NetFrameworkCoreTemplates ASP.NET Core Framework Templates
```

Same thing for vue-lite.

I installed the web app with the command

```
dotnet tool install -g web
```

then ran

```
web new react-lite rl
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be resolved with the latest version v0.0.21:

```
$ dotnet tool update -g web
```

Then should work:

```
$ web new react-lite ReactLite

Installing react-lite...

ReactLite react-lite project created.
```